# List active windows and their app icon filepaths ( from current icon theme ) - Xorg

Tags: bash, xorg, wmctrl, xprop

I can get the list of active windows by

`xprop -root _NET_CLIENT_LIST` , `wmctrl -l`

but how do i get their app icons too? preferrably from /usr/share/applications/appname.desktop! cuz these have highquality svg icons

OR

if it would be possible to get the filename.desktop of those windows then it will be very easy for me